# Consulta en 30 bases de datos

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo  30  bases de datos, cada base de datos es un punto de venta que esta ubicada en diferentes partes del país , las 30 bases de datos son iguales contienen las mismas tablas triggers etc...

Desde sql para hacer una consulta a los  30  puntos de venta cree un Local server Group es decir si consulto un SELECT  * FROM tblarticulos me va a traer las  30  tablas así mismo con cualquier consulta que haga

Necesito hacer esto mismo pero en un programa en c# es decir cada punto de venta tiene un segmento diferente o sea un servidor diferente 
ejemplo

Medellin tiene el  192.168.1.10

Cali tiene el  192.168.2.10

Barranquilla el  192.168.3.10

Así sucesivamente para los  30 puntos de venta

Como puedo hacer yo para conectar todas estas bases de datos en c# sin tener que hacer  30 conexiones, que sea como un server group de sql server que con una 
sola consulta la puedo hacer en todos sin necesidad de entrar a cada base de datos

Como puedo hacer esta conexión ¿? 
Como seria mas fácil y rápido ¿?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No puedes ni deberías por temas de seguridad conectarte remoto a una ip que expone la db a internet, salvo quizás por medio de una VPN para asegurar la comunicación.

Ahora bien lo que aconsejaría es que no tengas que conectarte a cada una de as 30 db, sino que traigas los datos que necesitas a una db central por medio del `servicio de replicación`.

[Replicación de SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2014)

[SQL Replication: Basic setup and configuration](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-replication-basic-setup-and-configuration/)

No me voy a explicar como es toda la configuración porque es largo, pero puedes definir publisher/subscritors para sincronizar los datos con una db central manteniendola actualizada

Entonces la consulta la realizas solo en esa única db central con los datos de todas las sucursales

Remarco nuevamente que esta funcionalidad debe ejecutar sobre un canal seguro usando VPN